# Need inputs about an architecture involving java and a messages queue

Tags: java, multithreading, message-queue

I need someone to answer a few questions about how to handle queues in Java.
This is a R&D project, I am in the very early phase of my researches, not java developper, sorry for the stupid questions.
I try to understand the picture of queues processing, with java

Here is my architecture

- I will have a queue, filled on amazon SQS (client spec)
- I need to process messages continously, I don't know when they will come or not.

Now I struggle to understand how it works to have one or more consumers that can process messages.

As far as I understand, a java program is compiled in a .jar.
How would you manage to have the .jar always "alive", waiting for messages to process ? 
Would you use a built-in langage feature or is it something that require a lib ?

Considering you are able to build a program written in java that is able to wait for messages to process, is there a risk of failure if there is no messages to process during a long time (let's say from few hours to few days). In this case do you need a manager like supervisord to restart periodically the program ?

Would you build a java program that is able to process many messages in parallel ? or would you run several instances of the consumer ? or both ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at on BlockingQueue in java

Answer (score 0):

There can be many answers to this question but I will try and simplify it. Your system is basically a message processing system.

What you want is something where you can get messages at any given point in time and you need to execute them as they come in.

The point of entry of your messages is the **Queue** you mentioned.

Now what you want is something which can look in the queue all the time and process those messages as they arrive.

Let's go with a very simple program first :

1. You have a part of program which constantly asks an API for messages.
2. As soon as the message arrives, you put it into a queue.
3. Something is constantly looping the queue in while(true) loop and process the message as it can see something was added in the queue.

Your program will be running forever because you will be instantiating 2 separate Threads, one which will be polling the API and the other which will be polling the queue. Which means your program will forever be running (Read more about Threads)

Now this approach is bad and has its drawbacks like what if we get millions of messages but you are unable to consume them all leading to your crew filling up and ending up blowing the entire program with an Out of Memory error. 
Another issue is that you are constantly polling the queue wasting cpu cycles. What if you have 100 messages in a queue and someone just terminates your program? You lose them all.

Let's go with another approach :

1. You continuously ask an API for the messages.
2. As soon as you get the message, you put it in the Queue BUT this time we make sure that the queue is blocking. That is you specify a size of the queue, the queue will not accept more messages as long as its at its specified capacity and hence it will apply back pressure on your API service ending up blocking it (making it slow down).
3. This blocking queue can be the part of a ThreadPool which process them. That is basically you submit the messages to the ThreadPool which internally has a blocking queue with the size you specify and the ThreadPool will execute the tasks on separate threads (Read more about ThreadPools here [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)) **Basically thread pool manages creation, destruction of threads for you and has an internal queue where you can submit tasks.**

With this approach you countered a lot of issues which we had in Approach 1. Lets say if your blocking queue is of size 8, you will just lose maximum of 8 messages if someone comes and kills your machine. This approach also makes sure that you don't blow up your machine with infinite messages. It also make sure that you don't end up wasting CPU cycles on polling the queue as now you execute small tasks as they arrive (Event Driven Programming where every message you get is an event. Read more here : [Event Driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming))

You will also need to add a shutdown hook in your program to make sure that the message reading service stops consuming messages and the ThreadPool shuts down executing all the pending tasks.

There is a lot more I can add in here like separating the message reading part to separate program and putting messages into a MessagingQueue like Kafka and having the processing part as a separate program which handles the message events.(Read more here [Messaging Queues](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19435-01/819-0069/intro.html)).

There is no risk of failure if your program runs idle for a long time.. :)
Yes the program will be parallel as you will be handling the events using separate threads (as long as you are using more than 1 processing Thread)

Comment: Thank a lot, this looks quite a job to code this program, do you know if there is a framework/lib, ready to use and that would be able to do this for me ?   Basically (I ask a lot I know), I would need a lib/framework that correctly handle all of theses features, and I would like to just have to code what to do with the message (just the business logic).
[Something like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-consumer)

In my project, messages are already published by another app, I am just responsible to process them. Thanks again

Comment: Well to be frank, its a very very basic problem :) you don’t need a framework for it. Just google for producer consumer using blocking queue and then go from there :) bringing framework this early will lead to more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

According to your use case it is typical [Publish–subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern .Various framework available for it.

For embedded system you can use

EventBus from Google Guava Library - "Publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another". It can also be an AsyncEventBus that will dispatch events on another thread.

or you can use jms queue.There is open source broker available like Activemq.

In a typical queue system you need three things.

**Brokers**

Brokers are simple system responsible for maintaining the pub-lished data. Each broker may have zero or more partitions per topic.For an example like kafka  Assume, if there are N partitions in a topic and N number of brokers, each broker will have one partition.

**Producers**

Producers are the publisher of messages to one or more Kafka topics. Producers send data to Kafka brokers. Every time a producer pub-lishes a message to a broker, the broker simply appends the message to the last segment file. Actually, the message will be appended to a partition. Producer can also send messages to a partition of their choice.

**Consumers**

Consumers read data from brokers. Consumers subscribes to one or more topics and consume published messages by pulling data from the brokers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, do you know if jms queue would be able to consume and publish messages to amazon SQS ?

Comment: You need a producer to publish the message to queue and listener to consume message.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this kind of mechanism .start the consumer thread at the beginning and add messages to the queue by calling producer method .

```
   import sms.send.sender.SEND;
   import sms.send.sender.SmsSender;

   public class SmsHandler {
   private static BlockingQueue<SEND> queue = new 
                              ArrayBlockingQueue<SEND>(50);

private volatile boolean running = true;

public void terminate() {
    running = false;

}

public void consumer() {
    System.out.println("Consumer thread is started");
    SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
    while (running) {   
        SEND sms = null;
        try {
            sms = queue.take();
            sender.send(sms.getMsisdn(), sms.getMessage());
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            running = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void producer(SEND send) {
    try {
        queue.put(send);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        running = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```